# jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(this).parent().children().children().css({})
```

можно сделать так? этот код работает?

Comment: проверь свой код здесь https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

Будет работать. в этом случаи вы получите

```
$(this).parent().children().children().css({})

Этот блок -> родитель -> ребенок -> ребенок.css
```

Только зачем сначала уходить к родителю, а потом возвращаться к ребенку - непонятно.

Не проще ли, если Вам нужно вернуться к родителю и найти какой-то блок дальше внутри вот так вот:

```js
$('input').on('click', function(){
 $(this).parents('.test').find('.child2').css('color', 'red')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='test'>
  <div class='child'>
    <input type='button' value='click'>
    <div class='child2'>
      test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Всё зависит от задачи, чтоб понять что проще, что нет. Вот например в приведенном вашем куске кода вообще достаточно написать `$(this).next().css('color', 'red')` и все телодвижения `.parents` и `find` не нужны

Comment: Конечно, я полностью согласен. :) Я хотел показать немного обобщенный способ поиска внутри родителя. Точно так же тут можно было использовать .siblings